# Probability that only one taxi arrives in a 2-minute interval and it's still waiting after 2 minutes

Tags: probability

Consider a taxi station where taxis and customers arrive in accordance with Poisson process with respective rates of one and two per minute. A taxi will wait no matter how many other taxis are present. However, an arriving customer that does not find a taxi waiting leaves. I'm trying to find the probability that precisely one taxi arrives between 11:00 and 11:02 and it's still waiting at 11:02.

I've been stuck for a while and not exactly sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Check out queuing models with reneging. Those describe these situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things need to happen:

- Exactly one taxi arrives between 11:00 and 11:02; let its arrival time be $T$.
- In the interval between $T$ and 11:02, no customers arrive. (However, any number of customers may arrive before $T$.)

Alternatively, these conditions can be equivalently expressed as

- The arrivals (either taxis of customers) between 11:00 and 11:02 are some [possibly zero] number of customers followed by a single taxi.

Note that by Poisson superposition the combined process of arrivals (of either type) has a rate of 3 arrivals per minute. So the probability that "there are $k$ arrivals in two minutes" is $e^{-6} 6^k/k!$, and conditioned on this, the probability that "the $k$ arrivals are $k-1$ customers followed by a single taxi" is $(2/3)^{k-1}(1/3)$. Thus, the final probability is
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-6} \frac{6^k}{k!} \frac{2^{k-1}}{3^k}
= \frac{e^{-6}}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{4^k}{k!}
= \frac{e^{-6}}{2} (e^4-1).$$

Comment: Am I missing something? What if there are already $n$ taxis waiting at time $T$? Then it would be okay for at most $n$ customers to arrive between $T$ and 11:02. So it seems like this problem is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Trailblazer Do you have any suggestion on how to approach this problem?

Comment: @Trailblazer Right, I've assumed that at 11:00 there are no taxis waiting. I may be wrong to make this assumption, but otherwise I don't think we have any information about the distribution of the number of taxis already waiting at 11:00.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a fix myself but I am sure if you search for queuing models with reneging eventually you will find something that is helpful here. There is definitely enough information to determine the distribution of taxis waiting at $T$ but it seems to be a complicated one.